# Why do I get "this CPU is not compatible with 64-bit mode" on a 64-bit processor?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, 64-bit, virtualbox, 32-bit

I have a 32-bit Ubuntu 10.10 as a host OS, VirtualBox 4.0, Windows 7 64-bit Professional as a guest OS. The laptop processor is 64-bit. When I try to load Windows 7 64-bit in VirtualBox, the error appears:

> attempting to load a 64-bit application, however this CPU is not compatible with with 64-bit mode

I don't understand, the CPU *is* compatible with 64-bit mode, what's the problem?

Comment: Please link us your processor name/model.

Comment: You must enable hardware virtualization through your BIOS

Comment: Achu, how? I'm trying to google but I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe it's telling you VirtualBox's virtual CPU, though, is not 64-bit compatible.  Is hardware virtualization enabled, and have you enabled VirtualBox's 64-bit support for the specific VM in question?

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests

> You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see the section called [“Hardware vs. software virtualization”](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt)).
>
> You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.

Comment: VT is disabled in the bios?

Comment: Also observe this requirement: "3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request." Make sure you select an OS with "(64 bit)" in its name.

Comment: I found it - my processor doesn't support hardware virtualization - that simple

Answer (score 0):

It may be because while the CPU supports 64-bit mode, its 64-bit mode is not enabled. Since the host OS is 32-bit, at boot, the CPU is only initialized into its 32-bit mode. So, since the virtualized OS is still using the same CPU as the guest OS, it can only operate in up to 32-bit mode. I believe you likely would have to have the host OS be 64-bit to be able to run the guest OS in 64-bit mode, as well.

Comment: VirtualBox does not require a 64-bit host to create a 64-bit guest

Answer (score -1):

Using Oracle VirtualBox, do the following:

- in VirtualBox settings, go to System, the Motherboard tab, and check the "Enable IO APIC" checkbox
- also in the BIOS, ensure virtualization technology is enabled. To get there, press <kbd>F10</kbd> (on an HP machine) when powering up your computer to take you to the setup screen (DOS-like background).

Comment: You should read some of the other comments and answers.  The author's hardware didn't support what he wanted to do.  Furthermore he was using a 32-bit host operating system, and VirtualBox doesn't support a 64-bit operating system on a 32-bit host.

Comment: @Ramhound: Not true.  If the processor supports 64-bit operation, 64-bit virtualization is possible, even if the guest operating system is 32-bit. See http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests